# Why can't get the value stored in a variable of the controller

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

here is my controller:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('HomeController', ['Factory',
                                  HomeController]);

    function HomeController(Factory){

      var result = Factory.query();

      this.model = result[0];

    }
})();
```

in the view I get the value by doing so

```
div(ng-controller='HomeController as HomeCtrl')
  h3{{HomeCtrl.model}}
```

the problem is I don't get any value. I am totally sure the value is returned from the factory since I have already tested the Factory.query() and I got the results. In fact If I do in the following way and get the value in the view by doing HomeCtrl.result[0], I get the result.

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('HomeController', ['Factory',
                                  HomeController]);

    function HomeController(Factory){

      this.result = Factory.query();

    }
})();
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the Factory? It seems you have a problem with how you deliver the data and how you expect it to be delivered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the factory's query method is most certainly an asynchronous method which immediately returns an empty array, but only populates it once the results of the asynchronous query are available (when it gets the response from an AJAX request, for example):

```
var query = function() {
    var result = [];
    $http.get('/somePath').success(function(data) {
        copyDataElementsTo(data, result); // 1 second later, the result is populated
    }
    return result; // returned immediately, empty
};
```

So, since your controller doesn't wait for the query result, it assigns `result[0]`, which is undefined at this moment, to its `model` variable.

Your second way of doing works because, in that case, the view re-renders itself as soon as the response to the asynchronous request has been received, so it reevaluates `result[0]`, which contains the elements received from the AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

You should use $scope to pass data to the view. That way, Angular will bind data and automatically update the view when your scope variable changes (your model variable is probably not available at the time the view renders due to an async call). Try something like this:

Controller

```
$scope.model = result[0];
```

View

```
h3{{model}}
```

Comment: The OP uses the `controller as` syntax, which binds the controller itself to the scope. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

Comment: The strange thing is that if I use result[0] it doesns't work while when I use result it works but I'm totally sure I got an array

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to get the first element of the array once it is populated, you can do so in the callback:

```
Factory.query(function(result) {
    this.model = result[0];
});
```